# Three.js arc drawing in canvas renderer is not working properly on Chrome anymore

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, three.js, updates

As we can see in this [example](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_interactive_particles.html) from the library, the circles are changing their line width and are very thin when they are close. This used to work fine.

My version of Chrome is:27.0.1453.93 and I am running it on an OSX 10.8.3.

How can we fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `programStroke()`, set `context.lineWidth = 1`.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks, I managed to fix it by inverting the rotation angle, like this:context.arc( 0, 0, 1, 0, -PI2, true ); I prefere your solution better.